# To the Calvinist, what does it mean that in the beginning God already has His object of wrath?

Tags: reformed-theology, romans, wrath-of-god

I have a Calvinist friend who told me that before the creation, God already knows the objects of His wrath. (I'm not a Christian).

I question him

1. "the objects of His wrath" is in a point of view in the beginning or
   in the end.
2. whether God wants His objects of wrath to repent or not

He gave me Romans 9:20-21 and told me the verse is telling that *"in the beginning God has decided to make some are the objects of His wrath and some are the objects if His mercy"*.

But when I read the verses, I found in verse 22 is telling

> **What if God**, although choosing to show his wrath and make his power
>   known, **bore with great patience the objects of his wrath**--prepared for
>   destruction?

So I said to my friend that even the writer of Romans still not sure about what he said in verse 20 and 21. This can be concluded when he say "What IF" in the verse 22.

Thanks for his pointing me out Romans 9:20-21 which made me also read the verse 22, it seems to me the answer of my question #2 is more likely (still not sure though) that *God wants the objects of His wrath to repent*, as the writer of Romans himself put a question on this case in his verse 22.

But then he starts to speak "bla-bla-bla" which to me is vague and not clear. He told me something like this : *"Before the creation God knows that ALL (every) man is the objects of His wrath. Still in before the creation, THEN He choose some of them to repent ... so, after the creation He made His chosen one to repent."*

To me, his explanation is more chronological in nature. Which raises the question: *"Before the creation, before He knows that all man is the objects of His wrath, before He choose some of them to repent, didn't God know who are the one in Heaven and Hell at the end of the world already ?"* From this question, it maybe can answer my question #1 : *"the objects of His wrath is in the point of view in the end (judgement day)"*. (still not sure though if this is what Calvinist think or not).

I'm asking here hoping to get a clear answer from an English speaking Calvinist.

Comment: Your interpretation of Romans and conclusion that Paul wasn't sure what he was writing is completely unjustified. There is a rhetorical device being used there and the "what if" is not an indication that the author is speculating. You could perhaps ask about this on [hermeneutics.se] if you want to know what's going on there.

Comment: But I'm concerned with this question that you seem to be trying to _disprove_ something more than you are trying to _understand_ it. Some parts of your friend's explanation may be unclear, but the issue with some seems more like you just disagree with him. This is a common problem when people try to understand bits of Reformed theology by examining just one piece transplanted into their own theological framework rather than in context of the other pieces of Reformed theology. Keep this in mind when reviewing answers: being "clear" and being "acceptable to your way of thinking" might not mesh.

Comment: @Caleb, thanks for your respond.  I just follow what my friend told me that *before the creation, God is already have His objects of wrath*. Suppose I am a newbie Calvinist, can't I ask that two questions in my first post ? If yes I can, then I think on the time I ask that two questions to him, it hasn't involved about I'm disagree or agree of what he said yet.  Also it hasn't involved that I'm already trying to disprove (or not) of what he said yet.

Comment: @Caleb, Oke... the author is not speculating on verse 22. So, *God wants His objects of wrath to repent or not* from this verse ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. And particularly for your question at the end: "Before the creation, before He knows that all man is the objects of His wrath, before He choose some of them to repent, didn't God know who are the one in Heaven and Hell at the end of the world already?" This doesn't really make sense if God is omniscient and knows the future, then he knows all the future. It doesn't make sense to talk about "before God knows something".

Comment: @curiousdannii, it's because my friend told me in chronology order before the creation : *(1) God knows that every man is the objects of His wrath. Then (2) He choose some of them to repent*. What he said is doesn't make sense to me, because I thought that God is omniscient :).

Comment: @curiousdannii, what I am asking is based on my Calvinist friend told me. The main questions are in my first post.

Comment: It sounds like you could be asking about [the infralapsarian/supralapsarian debate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_order_of_God's_decrees). If so, note that this is a debate within Reformed Theology and so there is not one single answer.

Comment: @curiousdannii, I just went there and read a little bit about it. It's a new information and it's quite interesting to me. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the use of "And what if" at the start of the sentence is a rhetorical device. It is not asking a question, thus making Paul unsure as to whether this is or is not the case. Rather, it follows on from his other rhetorical questions, e.g. "But who are you, O man, to answer back to God?"

John Calvin addresses this in his commentary on Romans (emphasis mine):

> A second answer, by which he briefly shows, that though the counsel
>   of God is in fact incomprehensible, yet his unblamable justice shines
>   forth no less in the perdition of the reprobate than in the salvation
>   of the elect. He does not indeed give a reason for divine election, so
>   as to assign a cause why this man is chosen and that man rejected; for
>   it was not meet that the things contained in the secret counsel of God
>   should be subjected to the judgment of men; and, besides, this mystery
>   is inexplicable. He therefore keeps us from curiously examining those
>   things which exceed human comprehension. He yet shows, that as far as
>   God’s predestination manifests itself, it appears perfectly just.
>
> **The particles, εἰ δὲ, used by Paul, I take to mean, *And what if*? so
>   that the whole sentence is a question; and thus the sense will be more
>   evident: and there is here an ellipsis, when we are to consider this
>   as being understood, — “Who then can charge him with unrighteousness,
>   or arraign him?” for here appears nothing but the most perfect course
>   of justice.**

Secondly, the objects of His wrath do not become the objects of His wrath AFTER their creation, because it says He *prepares* them. Taking into account also the context of Jacob and Esau being loved/hated before their birth, it is not a case of them being born, doing deeds, and *then* becoming objects of wrath. They are objects of wrath prepared for destruction from before their birth.

In Calvin's commentary on Romans, he also says the following:

> But if we wish fully to understand Paul, almost every word must be
>   examined. He then argues thus, — There are vessels prepared for
>   destruction, that is, given up and appointed to destruction: they are
>   also vessels of wrath, that is, made and formed for this end, that
>   they may be examples of God’s vengeance and displeasure. If the Lord
>   bears patiently for a time with these, not destroying them at the
>   first moment, but deferring the judgment prepared for them, and this
>   in order to set forth the decisions of his severity, that others may
>   be terrified by so dreadful examples, and also to make known his
>   power, to exhibit which he makes them in various ways to serve; and,
>   further, that the amplitude of his mercy towards the elect may hence
>   be more fully known and more brightly shine forth; — what is there
>   worthy of being reprehended in this dispensation? But that he is
>   silent as to the reason, why they are vessels appointed to
>   destruction, is no matter of wonder. He indeed takes it as granted,
>   according to what has been already said, that the reason is hid in the
>   secret and inexplorable counsel of God; whose justice it behoves us
>   rather to adore than to scrutinize.

From this we can understand that God does intend from the beginning to destroy those He has elected to be vessels of wrath, but He doesn't destroy them immediately. Rather, His wrath is deferred until the Day of Judgment.

Thirdly, your second question asks "Does God wants His objects of wrath to repent or not?" While this could be perhaps more thoroughly addressed, essentially He does not intend for His objects of wrath to ever repent. There is a general sense in which His will is for all men to repent, but His effective will is clear here; there are those chosen who will never repent, because God creates them such that they will never repent. We know that the gospel is for all men from various parts of the Bible, but we also know from various parts of the Bible that God has chosen those who will be saved and those who will not be saved.

Comment: thank you for your clear explanation from the Calvinist point of view. So, the answer of #1 is *"from the start"*. For example baby Cain soon as he was born, this baby is the object of His wrath... while baby Abel soon as he was born, this baby is the object of His mercy. Consequently, the answer of#2 is *"God never wants Cain (the object of His wrath) to repent"*. Am I correct here in interpreting your answers ?  Thank you once again, Birdie.

Comment: @karma There is a real sense that God always wants every sinner to repent. But Calvinists would say that that desire does not result in everyone being elect.

Comment: @curiousdannii, I understand that the Calvinisit would say that *God desires does not result in everyone being elect*, because *the election itself already done before God interact with any human* in the Calvinist pov. One thing that I still don't understand, why did God still bother to "warn" Cain which actually God himself knows that since a baby - Cain is His object of wrath ?

Comment: Isn't it just like an analogy that we know someone was born in completely stupid (absolute lack the ability to understand), yet we still bother to teach him ? Well I think  the logical answer from Calvinist will be : *we still bother to teach him is to prove that he was born completely stupid*. Make sense :).

Comment: All are born dead in sin and justly deserve God's condemnation.  It is all the more deserved when the non-elect are exposed to, but reject, the free offer of grace presented  in the gospel.  That God determined to save some by the blood of his son shows his great mercy to the elect.

Comment: @Robwest,  may I ask your imagination of Romans 9:21 *When a potter makes jars out of clay, doesn't he have a right to use the same lump of clay to make one jar for decoration and another to throw garbage into?* To me, the clay is neutral. From this neutral clay, the potter deliberately make "ugly" jar so then later on he can throw it to the garbage (because the jar is ugly) - and the potter deliberately make "beautiful" jar so then later on he can put in his table for decoration (because the jar is beautiful).

Comment: In verse 20, Paul said that neither the ugly jar nor the beautiful jar has the right to question the potter *"Why did you make me like this?"*. So the ugly one can not question *"Why did you make me ugly ?"* - and the beautiful one can not question *"Why did you make me beautiful ?"*